# lambda function return objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I made this code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

def kendalltau(ind):
    x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
    return stats.kendalltau(x, ind)[0]

selected = []
for i in range(5):
    selected.append(np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 5), replace=False, size=(5)))

distances = list(map(lambda ind: kendalltau, selected))

print(distances)
```

And it print this:

> [<function kendalltau at 0x000001A5D476BD08>, <function kendalltau at
> 0x000001A5D476BD08>, <function kendalltau at 0x000001A5D476BD08>,
> <function kendalltau at 0x000001A5D476BD08>, <function kendalltau at
> 0x000001A5D476BD08>]

Nevertheless, I would like to obtain an array of the *tau* value of the *kendalltau*, like so [0.482, -0.041, 0.788, 0.968, 0.325]

Any idea ?

Thank you

Aymeric

Comment: Did you mean: `distances = list(map(lambda ind: kendalltau(ind), selected))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the above:

```
distances = list(map(lambda ind: kendalltau, selected))
```

to this:

```
distances = list(map(kendalltau, selected))
```

the issue with your code is you are using lambda expression that returns a executable, but inside it you do not execute anything, so there is executeable that return another executeable which is useless.. just send the function you have defined and the `map` will execute it for each item

Answer (score 1):

You still need to pass the argument ind to kendalltau in the lambda function call
it should be

```
distances = list(map(lambda ind: kendalltau(ind), selected))
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth pointing this error out without explaining that the lambda expression serves no purpose here.

Comment: You are right, i'm just fishing for reputation :)

Comment: What @chepner is saying (I guess) is that `list(map(kendalltau, selected))` is enough.